Doubt regarding limiting distribution on Vasicek model
I was reading an article from Vasicek  where he's concerned about deriving the limiting loss probability distribution on a credit risk model with 2 factors.
I am here presenting a somewhat different proof presented in chapter 4 of Bolder.
In equation 4.45 he writes
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}ODR_N=p(G)\bigg|G\right)=1
\end{equation}
where $ODR_N$ denotes the observed proportion of defaulting clients in a portfolio with N clients, $p(\cdot)$ is a non-linear function which can be derived from the two factor model (not relevant for my question) and $G\sim N(0,1)$ denotes the systemic risk factor.
He then proceeds to say that for big values of $N$ the following holds true:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(ODR_N\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(p(G)\leq x)
\end{equation}
What confuses me is that the first equation says that conditional on $G$ the observed proportion of defaulting clients converges to the true value.
The second one instead assumes that the (unconditional) distribution are equal for big values of N.
I fail to see why the second equation holds true.
I would appreciate if you could explain me why the latter is true.
